# D3 pie chart with dynamic Data in Angular 8

Tags: angular, d3.js

I am creating a `d3` Pie Chart in Angular 8, The chart created with out any problem. 
The data is static like this

**static data**

```
  samples: PieGraph[] = [
    { name: "Emirates", value: 202921689.73000002 },
    { name: "DHL", value: 32839771.62 },
  ];
```

when I fetch data from API and push it to `samples` array chart disappears.

*I think, chart created before the slices get values from service*

**service**

```
this.data.forEach(x => {
          Object.entries(x.data.tnge.airline).forEach(([key, value]) => {
            console.log(key, value, "sadfasdfsd");
            this.samples.push({ name: key, value: value });
          });
        });
console.log(this.samples, "sample ==== Data");
```

**console**

*Green*: show only 2 items, even shows the data is populated properly. and Pie Chart show only 2 slice.

*Red* Data is from `Services`.

[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcEh5.png)

Comment: You have to check data created first after that create id for chart with `*ngIf` condition